# Google Cloud Vision API - Partial matching image

Tags: search-engine, google-cloud-vision

I am using the Google Cloud Vision API to search similar images (web detection) and it works pretty well. Google detects full matching images and partial matching images (cropped versions).

I am looking for a way to detect more different versions. For example, when I look for a logo, I would like to detect large, small, square, rectangular ... versions of this logo. For now, I detect images that match exactly the one I upload and cropped versions.

Do you know if this is possible and how can I do that?

Comment: The question seems to be too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The **Web entities** feature supports the detection of exact and partial matches of the image as well as the URLs of visually similar images, as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/other-features#web_entities); however, keep in mind that these objects need to have certain percentage of similarity with the original image which means that the objects that doesn't satisfy these parameters cannot be detected by the model.

In case this feature doesn't cover your current needs, you can use the **Send Feedback** button, located at the lower left and upper right corners of the [service public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/other-features#web_entities), as well as take a look the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) tool in order to [raise a Vision API feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1010433) and notify to Google about this desired functionality.